# prolog gives Undefined procedure: atom_length/4

Tags: prolog, maplist

I'm trying to use maplist to filter a list of elements by limiting the length of each of the element, and here is what I tried

```
maplist(atom_length(2,X),[aa,bb,cc,asd],Result).
ERROR: apply:maplist_/3: Undefined procedure: atom_length/4
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         atom_length/2
```

I expect to get

```
Result = [aa,bb,cc]
```

A little help is required. Thanks.

Comment: 1. maplist/2 is not a filtering predicate. 2. The arguments of atom_length are: atom_length(Atom, Length). 3. You either need an auxiliary predicate or use lambdas.

Comment: @false Just realize the typo in atom_length in the question, it's not directly copied from the terminal. I will research on lambdas. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A predicate that provides the functionality you require is `findall_member/4`. You can find a description and an implementation of this predicate in the [Richard O'Keefe Prolog library proposal](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pllib.htm). For example:

```
| ?- findall_member(Atom, [aa,bb,cc,asd], atom_length(Atom,2), Result).
Result = [aa, bb, cc]
yes
```

The third argument of the `findall_member/4` predicate is a test that is applied to each member of the list to filter the results.

Comment: it works, I might further investigate on a easy understandable method. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a clarification about Paulo answer: you can combine library predicates, like

```
?- findall(X, (member(X,[aa,bb,cc,asd]),atom_length(X,2)), L).
L = [aa, bb, cc].
```

`member/2` acts as generator, `atom_length/2` as filter.

Comment: Indeed, Richard's implementation (to be read as a specification; implementations that don't use `findall/3` are easy and often preferable), is a call to `findall/3`.

Comment: As a side note, and as mentioned in the link to Richard's proposal, ideally the compiler optimizes calls to `findall_member/4` by generated code (using e.g. the term-expansion mechanism) that avoids calling `findall/3` by traversing the list and avoiding the implicit meta-call of the test argument (the Logtalk implementation of this predicate does just that if you're curious for an example).